# Why the solution to $\frac{dx}{dt}= x(4-x^2) + \sin t$ is bounded with |x(0)|<3?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I met this problem in an ODE exam and I am confused.

To directly solve it is clearly not an optimal way. But I struggle to find any starting point. Periodicity also plays a role here.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $x^2(4-x)$ or $x(4-x)$?

Comment: @eyeballfrog sorry! edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $x=3$ the derivative has the bound
$$
\dot x\le -15+1<0
$$
at $x=-3$
$$
\dot x \ge 15-1 > 0
$$
This means that the region $|x|\le 3$ is a trapping region in forward direction.